# What service account is my code running with?

Tags: go, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus

### First some background

We're running a kubernetes cluster with a pod with a container that's provided by Google (`prometheus-to-sd` to be precise, we use it to get custom metrics into google cloud monitoring fka stackdriver).
The pod was running fine, until we enabled Workload Identity on the cluster.

The pod currently runs with application default credentials, which used to be a service account that was set up to have the gcp role `monitoring.writer`.

When we introduced Workload Identity, the application default credentials changed and the `prometheus-to-sd` container started complaining about a missing permission `monitoring.timeSeries.create`.

I tried setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to a file that's mounted from a gke secret.
I verified the file is there and that the environment var is set (`kubectl exec -it $POD /bin/sh`).

I'm trying to debug what's going wrong.

### The programming question

I want to write some go code to verify which gcp service account is running, but all the examples show a `Client` which is an http client with the authorization headers setup.
See https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client

For example:

```
import (
        "context"
        "fmt"
        "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()

    creds, err := google.FindDefaultCredentials(ctx)
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", *creds)
    
}
```

This prints something along the lines:

```
{ProjectID:projectId TokenSource:0xc000120880 JSON:[/* big chunk of byte values, no idea what these mean */]}
```

Now I could load the file myself, but that defeats the purpose of testing whether the mechanism in selecting the default credentials.

I've also looked at other languages like nodejs, but basically the same problem shows. The code is running with some credentials and it's not clear which ones are used.

Comment: I may be off...but you might want to read this article for some service account hints: https://blog.openshift.com/kerberos-sidecar-container/

Comment: That article seems to be describing a linux level account, the google apis operate completely in "user space".

Comment: Then I am definitely "off"!!  My apologies.

Comment: If something is unclear, try to read the source :D https://github.com/golang/oauth2/blob/master/google/default.go#L76 However, there is an email in the json content, that will tell you which service account is running.

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a GSA that has monitoring.timeSeries.create permission and bind it to a KSA and use that KSA for your pod. See here https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#creating_a_relationship_between_ksas_and_gsas

Comment: @BrianPursley That's indeed the end goal. However while transitioning I'd rather have the container use a service account key file explicitly and then phase that out with WI.
The default GSA currently has too many rights, that's why it is working currently, but setting an explicit GSA key file with GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS doesn't seem to be working, so I want a diagnostics tool to output what account is being picked up by the google apis in go.

Comment: unless you define explicite credentials in your code, it will run using the nod service account